# type function<type>()

Tags: c#, xna

I saw something like this in some graphics libs today, and it seems like it could be very usefull.

In the demo I saw it looked like this:

```
Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures//Road");
Effect shader = Content.Load<Effect>("Effects//Road");
```

I assume it's a function that returns whatever type is defined in the <> brackets, and does a different action for different types.

I want to implement something similar myself, how is it used?

Comment: Looks like....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx perhaps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Load` method can be used to load lots of different types of content, including things like images and sounds.  Therefore, it may return instances of different Types (such as your `Texture2d` and `Effect`).

There are two ways of creating a method that can do this.  First, and most simply, you can return an `Object`, which is the base class of every type in the .NET and XNA world.

```
public object Load(string path) { /*...*/}
```

you would have to use it thusly:

```
Texture2D texture = (Texture2D)Content.Load("Textures//Road");
```

The second way is to use generics.  With generics, you can handle the cast for the user, making their code simpler.  A generic version of this method would be:

```
public T Load<T>(string path)
{
    return (T)Load(path);
}
```

You're still using the old load, but you're performing the cast (to whatever type that T is) prior to returning the value.

Generics are useful, as you can use them to create type safe code without creating lots and lots of type-specific method versions, like

```
public Texture2d LoadTexture2d(string path)
{
    return (Texture2d)Load(path);
}    
public Effect LoadEffect(string path)
{
    return (Effect)Load(path);
}
//500 more versions omitted for brevity
```

Comment: Very informative, thanks. So is there any way to branch depending on what type "T" is?

Comment: @Hannesh yes, by `if(instance is SomeType) {}`, however I'd consider that a major code smell when done in a generic method.

Answer (score 9):

It's called *generics*.

### Example:

```
public T ConvertValue<T>(Object value)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

### References:

[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: the type in the <>'s isn't necessarily the type that will be returned.  that's often what generic methods do but not always.

Comment: @Robert: That is correct. But, my example suits the scenario mentioned by OP.

Comment: yup, i was just adding a data point that i didn't think warranted being posted as a competing answer

Answer (score 2):

Its called Generics a great way to specify methods and classes for Type Independent programming. Generics allow you to define type-safe data structures, without committing to actual data types. This results in a significant performance boost and higher quality code, because you get to reuse data processing algorithms without duplicating type-specific code.

### A simple example  of stack:

```
public class Stack<T>
{
   T[] m_Items; 
   public void Push(T item)
   {...}
   public T Pop()
   {...}
}
Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
stack.Push(1);
stack.Push(2);
int number = stack.Pop();
```

Above class will work for any type like string or your custom class's object
Look Here for Complete Description

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topica

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Load method defines indeed what it should return and so that is already defined for you. Inside the Load method, the contentLoader decides how to load it. There are a couple of XNA examples on loading your own kind of data as well. If you create something like an: `.world`-file. You can create your own AssetLoader that specifies how to load your own kind of data.

1. http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/custom_model_importer
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb447743.aspx